# Counting the total number of connection under a person in Python

Tags: python, networking, graph

thank you for helping!
I am quite a beginner to coding so forgive me.

[image]

In this table, it shows how 6 people are connected to each other.
I want to find out how many connection (direct and indirect), a person has under him/her.
Example, "A" is a boss and has 2 employees, A's employees have employees, how many people are all under A.

output for "A" = 5 connections under him/her

output for "C" = 2 connections under him/her

in the real data, the number of boss and employee is more.
I am trying to have a function/df that will input a boss/employee and output total number under the person/df.

Here is my WRONG answer :(

```
em = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
em

#collapse to dictionary

dict_a = {k: g["employee"].tolist() for k,g in em.groupby("name")}
dict_a

output: 
{'A': ['B', 'C'],
 'B': ['D'],
 'C': ['E', 'F'],
 'E': ['H', 'I'],
 'H': ['T', 'U', 'V']}

#counting the len of value in dictionary
list1= []
list2=[]

for k,v in dict_a.items():
    list1.append(k)
    list2.append((len(list(filter(None, v)))))
    
df_emp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['person', 'count'])
df_emp['person'] = list1
df_emp['count']=list2

#this is wrong because i could only direct report but not indirect report
df_emp
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Specifically what data structure the data is in, that'll change a lot about the program.

Comment: sure let me edit the question to put that info in

Comment: Look up some basic algorithms in traversing the data structure known as a ""tree", a special form of a "directed graph".  Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data structure that maps keys to their connections using `collections.defualtdict`. One you have that it's a very succinct recursive function to make the counts:

```
from collections import defaultdict
   
cons = [
    ('A','B'),
    ('A','C'),
    ('B','D'),
    ('C','E'),
    ('C','F')
]

# make an adjacency list:
connections = defaultdict(set)

for k, v in cons:
    connections[k].add(v)

# recursive function to count lengths:
def numCons(k,connections):
    if k not in connections:
        return 0
    # number of direct connections plus their connections:
    return len(connections[k]) + sum(numCons(child_k, connections) for child_k in connections[k])

numCons('A', connections)
# 5
numCons('C', connections)
# 2
numCons('E', connections)
# 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that your data is defined as below:

```py
maps = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['D'], 'C': ['E', 'F']}
```

Then you can count connections recursively

```py
def get_connections(k, maps):
    if k not in maps:
        return 0

    count = len(maps[k])
    for member in maps[k]:
        count += get_connections(member, maps)
    return count

connections = dict()
for k, v in maps.items():
    connections[k] = get_connections(k, maps)

print(connections)
```

But some people may have a relationship with each other.
For example, use these data:

```py
maps = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['D'], 'C': ['E', 'F'], 'E': ['A']}
```

In this case, we should maintain already counting members.
(But this code has a bug counting 'A' twice)

```py
def get_connections(k, maps, already_counting):
    if k not in maps:
        return 0
    if k in already_counting:
        return 0

    count = len(maps[k])
    for member in maps[k]:
        count += get_connections(member, maps, already_counting+[k])
    return count

connections = dict()
for k, v in maps.items():
    connections[k] = get_connections(k, maps, [])

print(connections)
```

Comment: is there a non recursive way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with recursive call

```
dict = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
      'B': ['D'],
      'C': ['E', 'F'],
      'E': ['H', 'I'],
      'H': ['T', 'U', 'V']}
def connections():
    for k,v in dict.items():
        l=len(v)
        for k1 in v:
            l=connectionscount(l,k1)

        print(k+":"+str(l))
def connectionscount(l,k):
    if k in dict:
        kv=dict[k]
        l+=len(kv)
        for k1 in kv:
            l=connectionscount(l,k1)
        return l
    else:
        return l
```

Output:

A:10

B:1

C:7

E:5

H:3

Comment: for L. is L the number of values each key contains?

Comment: is there a non recursive way to do it?